# WSO2 Governance Registry - unable to download the WSDL with the schema dependencies having the namespace as the folder structure

Tags: wso2

We have Added the WSDL url in WSO2 governance registry. The Registry has shown the uploaded WSDL and the schema dependencies. When ever we tried to download the WSDL, its getting the Zip file where it has WSDL and schema dependencies in the folder called dependencies. We expected a folder structure similar to namespace of the schema. I want to know how to achieve with the customization.
For example
my WSDL has imported one schema file welcome.xsd where its namespace is com.mycompany.common.v1. When i added the WSDL url in  registry, the imported schema's in WSDL are in the folder structure com.mycompany.common.v1. When i downloaded the WSDL, i am expecting the Zip file should contain a WSDL and dependent schemas in folder structure com/mycompany/common/v1.

Answer (score 0):

The "Download" option hasn't been designed to achieve your target. 
But using the Governance/Registry API you can create a WSDL zip file having the namespace as the folder structure.

Thanks
Ajith.